# How to Reduce the Number of if controller for better performance of test plan in JMeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Here I'm  using 10 if controller in JMeter to run my requirement in test plan each if controller consisting Get and Post request with csv data here in counter i set like this

Start :1

increment:1

Maximum:10

Numberformat:00

Reference name:tcounter

like this counter increment one by one if controller will executes according to counter value so Here this is the causing issue that performance of slow down  JMeter will slow and stackoverflowexception and more over i am not getting proper output when i will run my test plan  please tell me how to reduce the Number of if controller,or  is there any alternative to if controller.

Answer (score 1):

In the majority of programming languages it is recommended to use [switch statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) instead of multiple [if statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)#If.E2.80.93then.28.E2.80.93else.29).

So you can refactor your script to use single [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) rather than having many If Controllers.

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more information